# How To Select Some Data from JSON

Tags: json

Please Read the json data below carefully

```
{
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "675": {
        "Offer": {
          "name": Vivek
        }
      },
      "787": {
        "Offer": {
          "name": Aashiq
        }
      }
    },
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
}
```

I want to select the integer 675 & 787 from the above json data and inserting in Mysql  using php currently I am using bellow php code. Help me to select this integer and thanks.

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
include 'db.php';

$json = {
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "675": {
        "Offer": {
          "name": Vivek
        }
      },
      "787": {
        "Offer": {
          "name": Aashiq
        }
      }
    },
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
};


$mydata = json_decode($json, true);

////mysql///
foreach ($mydata["response"]["data"] as $key => $value)
    echo $key;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO due
    (integer) VALUES('$key')")
    or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) function should help you out:

```
$result_str = '{ "response": { "status": 1, "httpStatus": 200, "data": { "675": { "Offer": { "name": Vivek } }, "787": { "Offer": { "name": Aashiq } } }, "errors": [], "errorMessage": null } }'

$result_json = json_decode($result_str);
$data = $result_json->response->data;
print $data->{'675'};
print $data->{'787'};
```

See also [json_decode Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below way to read this via JQuery

```
var data={
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "675": {
        "Offer": {
          "name": "Vivek"
        }
      },
      "787": {
        "Offer": {
          "name": "Aashiq"
        }
      }
    },
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
};

var innerData = data.response.data;

jQuery.each(innerData,function(key,value)
{
    console.log(key);
});
```